# Headphones are 'turning on' with awful noise

Tags: windows-7, headphones

Headphones do awful noise for 3-7 seconds after some application starts to use them. For example, when I start a computer game or open Youtube video. After the noise they start to sound normally. When no applications use them, after 3-7 minutes I can hear, that they again 'turned off', and when any application use them again, the awful loud noise repeats.

Seems like something is 'turning them off' and then 'turning on', but it turns on for several seconds and gives me noise while doing it. I want to disable such behaviour but don't know how.

- headphones Razer Orca
- motherboard ASUS M2NE-570 Ultra
- Windows 7 SP1
- some SoundMax drivers from ASUS website are installed

Comment: wanted to add tag [sound-noise]

Comment: sound-noise sounds like a meta-tag - it dosen't mean very much without context. The question is fine as it is. Does the same thing happen with speakers? Have you tried the headphones on a different port? (front vs read?)